# how to add 10 to a variable inside a jquery function

Tags: jquery

I want to make a loadmore button and i everytime i click the load button the var start will be added by 10 each coicks. It works but it only gets the first 10 data. I want it to add 10 each clicks.## Help ## j added a plus 10 but it dont add 10.

```
$("btn").click(function(){
var start = 10;
start + 10;
});
```

Comment: i edited the post, because it wont let me post a question if i insert the code.

Comment: Every time you click the button you set `start` back to 10. Try setting `start` outside the function. And change the `+ 10` to `+= 10`

Comment: what u mean? Can u add a answer and then elaborate.

Comment: Maybe try using one of many search-engines first, and explore the world of actually learning how to code, instead of just getting straight up answers spit out for you.

Comment: I tried, but they dont give a in depth explanations, so i try to ask many questions as i could to learn something new, rather than copying without understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna add `+10` to start each time then you need to assign it back like below:

```
var start = 10;
$("btn").click(function(){
   start += 10; //or start=start+10
});
```

Comment: @Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 3):

**[Variable Scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx)**
For accomplishing this we use Global variables.

These variables are created in the `<script>` block, before the scope of functions which use it starts.

```
var start = 0; //define it as a global variable.
$("btn").click(function(){
    start + 10;
});
```

Comment: Thanks ill try that. Thanks so much.